# how to search full string in rad combobox bound items like IntelliSense

Tags: full-text-search, intellisense, radcombobox, listboxitems

**> how to search full string in rad combobox bound items like

> IntelliSense**

note that its cantain more than 3000 items , i have to make search specification like IntelliSense ..

Comment: Are you saying that you want to search through 3000 records or want to have the combobox list 3000 items?

Comment: here combo box items dynamically populating from database, and it combobox items near about 3000 or greater ,so here i need search options like IntelliSense.